# How do I send and receive the ajax request instead of grabbing the code from the main.js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am trying to do a AJAX request with server side Node JS and client side Jquery.

Currently my client-side code looks like this:

```
let theSearchRequest = $("#search").val();

                $.ajax({
                    method:"GET",
                    url:"./main.js",
                    data: theSearchRequest
                })
                .done( (theListOfNames) => {
                    $("#listOfNames").html(theListOfNames);
                });
```

my server-side code looks like this:

```
let request = require("request");

let names = ["ryan", "liam", "john", "james", "michael"];

request.get({
    url:"./index.html",
},
(error, response, body) =>{
    console.log(body);

});
```

the output is that the "p" tag with the id "listOfNames" shows the server side code.

How do I send and receive the ajax request instead of grabbing the code from the main.js file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass search input in any specific key

```
let theSearchRequest = $("#search").val();
$.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url:"./main.js",
    data: {search: theSearchRequest}
})
.done( (theListOfNames) => {
    $("#listOfNames").html(theListOfNames);
});
```

On server-side, you will get search input in the query string parameter.

```
let request = require("request");
let names = ["ryan", "liam", "john", "james", "michael"];
request.get({
    url:"./index.html",
},
(error, response, body) =>{
    console.log(body.query);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery ajax request you are calling `url:"./main.js"` which actually is a file (a javascript file).

I assume `main.js` is your server side code, right? 
What you want to do, is to call not `main.js` but `index.html` in your ajax request on the client side.

On top, you should convert the searchRequest value to a query string and send that to the server.

```
let theSearchRequest = $("#search").val();
//e.g.
let theSearchRequestQueryString = 'searchRequest=' + theSearchRequest;
$.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url:"./main.js",
    data: theSearchRequestQueryString
})
.done( (theListOfNames) => {
    $("#listOfNames").html(theListOfNames);
});
```

I can't tell if this is what you really want to achieve (calling the `index.html` file).

In order to work anyway, the node.js server needs to run.